# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: none)

Tags: python

I'm getting this type of error when installing the library.
Not for all packages, but only for some. Is it because pip version? or Because of python interpreter?
Plz guide me what should I do.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to install this package because it's already in the standard library.

Just `import time` in any Python file.

Comment: So whenever I get this type of error, it means I already have that package?

Comment: Unfortunately that conclusion can't be made; that pip error means that the package isn't available at all. But in this case, since it is `time`, it's common knowledge for Python programmers that this is a standard library which is built-in.

Comment: then what should I do when this type of error occurs again?

Comment: Type in the package name in Google with the word python, and see what comes up. Maybe you'll find a github, or something in the Python docs :)

Comment: Look for a tutorial that offers a quick tour through the Python standard library, such as https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html . Some acquaintance with the standard library is indispensable, as you have discovered.